# Servicio Web. Error 401. Acceso denegado

Tags: vb.net, webservice, autenticación

Tengo un sistema web (en vb.net) que consume un servicio web (vb.net) que tenia autenticación anónima en el IIS y funcionaba ok. Ahora debe tener autenticación básica y de windows y dejó de funcionar.
Me da error "Error de la solicitud con el código de estado HTTP 401: Unauthorized."

La invocación al servicio web tiene este código:

```
`Dim ServicioRemotoEntes As New ServicioRemotoEntes.EntesSvc`
`Dim sUsrServicioWeb As String = "USUARIOEJEMPLO"`
`Dim sPwdServicioWeb As String = "123456"`
`Dim sDmnServicioWeb As String = "MIDOMINIO"`

`Dim oNetCredencial As System.Net.NetworkCredential = New NetworkCredential(sUsrServicioWeb, sPwdServicioWeb)`
`ServicioRemotoEntes.Credentials = oNetCredencial`
`ServicioRemotoEntes.PreAuthenticate = True`

`ResultadoArrayEntesRemoto = ServicioRemotoEntes.GetEntesTodos(prefixText)`
```

Intenté con credenciales, sin credenciales, con proxy, sin proxy, con CredencialCache, nada me funcionó.
Por otro lado tengo la misma situación con otro sistema (c#) y otro servicio web (C#) que no funcionaban con esa autenticación y le pase las credenciales como escribi arriba y funciona perfecto.

Quien pueda ayudar
Gracias!